# Sessão não identificada em alguns logins no django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-rest-framework

estou fazendo uma manutenção em uma app Django versão 1.5 com DRF 2.3. Essa app possui uma autenticação de usuários fora do padrão do Django, e que funciona bem. Veja um resumo abaixo:

accounts/views.py

```
class Autentica(TemplateView):
template_name = 'checkuser.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request.session['token'] = request.GET['token']
    self.request.session['idUser'] = request.GET['idUser']
    #resto do código ...
```

Porém quando tento acessar essas duas variaveis de sessão (idUser e token) por meio de outro endpoint do mesmo sistema (EM ALGUNS CASOS) os valores de "idUser" e "token" não existem, como se não tivessem sido definidos na autenticação, sendo que fiz o mesmo processo e verifiquei no método de autenticação e ambos os valores estão sendo definidos normalmente.

Aqui está o endpoint que estou tentando acessar

core/views.py

```
class PainelGestaoUsuariosView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
def get(self, request):
    # OUTROS TRATAMENTOS....  
    idUser = self.request.session['idUser']
    token  = self.request.session['token']
    #ou request.session['...'] 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('%URLPARAOSISTEMATERCEIRO/check?token=%s&idUser=%s'%(token,idUser))
```

Obs.:

- Habilitei o 'django.contrib.sessions' e 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' no settings.py
- Praticamente quase todos logins funcionam (consigo acessar as variáveis de sessão), salvo 3 logins que não encontrei diferença.
- Como a autenticação é feita de forma diferente a padrão do django o **request.user** é igual a "Anonymous User" mas acredito que não tenha influenciado nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, no final das contas devido ao cansaço não percebi um detalhe exdrúxulo porém não menos importante, que é a URL a qual você faz um redirect, cuja a qual estava no ALLOWED_HOSTS sem o www. Item resolvido!